# Deciding how to pass selected file from Open File Dialog to another form

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I am having a problem with thinking of a way that would let me pass a selected file to another form.

I am trying to select a file in Form 1 by using Open File Dialog and then pass the same file to Form 2 in which I will try to add another entry into a file.

The problem is that I am nnot sure what I should be passing. Should I pass only `openFileDialog.FileName` or I need to pass more than just this?

I was thinking of this all day today but I don't know how should I do this? Which parts of Open File Dialog should I pass over?

Or.. I might just thinking too hard of this problem. Please clear my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            Form2 frm2;
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                frm2 = new Form2();
            }
            private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    frm2.FileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    frm2.Show();
                }
            }
        }

    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        string _fileName = "";
         public string FileName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._fileName;
            }
            set
            {
                this._fileName = value;
            }
        }
    }
```